# Python with Proxy

Tags: python, proxy

I want to write a python program that can run packets through my local proxy server. But just as a heads-up, I know about requests library and I dont want to use the proxy option that comes with it. It only supports http/https. I want to be able to pass my port scans through proxies in python. Basically I'd like to make it so it runs as if I ran the script with "proxychains". Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the socket library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proxy that handles arbitrary network protocols is called a SOCKS proxy. `pysocks` is the package that can help you. From the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/):

```
import socks

s = socks.socksocket() # Same API as socket.socket in the standard lib

s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost") # SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 use port 1080 by default
# Or
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS4, "localhost", 4444)
# Or
s.set_proxy(socks.HTTP, "5.5.5.5", 8888)

# Can be treated identical to a regular socket object
s.connect(("www.somesite.com", 80))
```